# jQuery input field format into XX-XX-XX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I couldn't find a plugin suitable for this.
I want to be able to format the way the user would be able to input in the field.

```
XX-XX-XX
```

Where X is any digits from 0-9

Comment: Great! What have you tried and what are you struggling with?

Comment: 'jQuery input mask' first hit in google: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Wow, thank you very much.  I should have used the *MASK* keyword when looking for a plugin instead of field format.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Masked input :
[Masked Input Library](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo)

It should help you.

Comment: Thanks dude.  Alot of harsh comment here, I was simply searching on the wrong keyword, thus making it hard for me to find the right suitable plugin.  Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Read http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/javascript-input-masks/

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Oh with [Google][1]

[1]: https://www.google.ro/?gws_rd=ssl#hl=ro&gs_nf=1&pq=input format jquery library&cp=19&gs_id=141&xhr=t&q=masked input plugin&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=masked input plugin&aq=0L&aqi=g-L3&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=bf2149430d246ba1&biw=1280&bih=886