# jquery auto add comma in custom format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add auto comma in input field. I've searched about it and also found many answer and references, but I can't found exact what I wish. Almost all answers cover same digit pattern. Following code generates:`22,10,2015`. But I want to in this format `2015,10,22`.

I have used following code, and try to customize, but can't succeed.

```
$('#your-id').bind('keyup','keydown', function(event) {
    var inputLength = event.target.value.length;
    if (event.keyCode != 8) {
        if(inputLength === 2 || inputLength === 5) {
            var thisVal = event.target.value;
            thisVal += ',';
            $(event.target).val(thisVal);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: is this a date input? and you are using any plugin for this date input?

Comment: Duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529792/jquery-input-field-format-into-xx-xx-xx

Comment: @Nirali, it is not date input, though it seems date, user enter random input and I want to add comma with above criteria.

Comment: @Saeed.At, I wish not using plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure I didn't understand your question properly, but all you need is change the lengths of you if condition.

Try this:

```js
$('#your-id').bind('keyup','keydown', function(event) {
  var inputLength = event.target.value.length;
  if (event.keyCode != 8){
    if(inputLength === 4 || inputLength === 7){
      var thisVal = event.target.value;
      thisVal += ',';
      $(event.target).val(thisVal);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="your-id">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="text" onkeyup="valid()">
<script>
  function valid(){
    var text=document.getElementById("text").value;
    var ne_text=text.split(",").join("").split("");
    var li_text="";
    for(var i=0;i<ne_text.length;i++){
      li_text+=ne_text[i];
      if(i==3 && i<ne_text.length-1){
        li_text+=",";
      }else if(i==5 && i<ne_text.length-1){
        li_text+=",";
      }else if(i==7){
        document.getElementById("text").value=li_text;
        break;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("text").value=li_text;
  }
</script>
```